# Global declaration for a variable with changing name

Tags: tcl

I have created variables based on the port number of a device. How can I declare them as global so that I can use them in a different function?

```
  set txresults_$portIndex [stc::get $generator1 \
                        -children-GeneratorPortresults] 

  set rxresults_$portIndex [stc::get $Analyzer1 \
                        -children-AnalyzerPortresults]
```

Comment: Either `global` or scope resolution operator `::` will do the job. E.g. `set ::txresults_$portIndex <SOMEVALUEHERE>`

Comment: Also, whenever you have a name like `txresults_$portIndex`, consider using an array instead: `txresults($portIndex)` (using `global txresults` or `::txresults` to make it global).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `global` command can be put anywhere in a procedure, not just at the top of it.

```
proc yourprocedure {...} {
    set portIndex [something here]

    # ...

    global txresults_$portIndex rxresults_$portIndex
    set txresults_$portIndex [stc::get $generator1 \
                          -children-GeneratorPortresults] 
    set rxresults_$portIndex [stc::get $Analyzer1 \
                          -children-AnalyzerPortresults]

    # ...
}
```

## However…

It's probably a bad idea to do that, as working with variable-named variables is a bit annoying (you can do it with `[set …]` instead of `$…`, or by making an alias with `upvar`, but it's still annoying). Instead, you probably should use arrays instead, as that makes the code much easier to understand:

```
proc yourprocedure {...} {
    global txresults rxresults

    set portIndex [something here]

    # ...

    set txresults($portIndex) [stc::get $generator1 \
                          -children-GeneratorPortresults] 
    set rxresults($portIndex) [stc::get $Analyzer1 \
                          -children-AnalyzerPortresults]

    # ...
}
```

When you do that, you group all those variable-named variables into collections of variables — arrays — and you get to then refer to them elsewhere by doing just:

```
    global txresults
    do-something-with $txresults($portIndex)
```

That's better in understandability terms than these alternatives:

```
    global txresults_$portIndex
    do-something-with [set txresults_$portIndex]
```

```
    upvar ::txresults_$portIndex txr
    do-something-with $txr
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Donal.